# Can I get Excel to fill a range of numbers between two cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given the table below:

[image]

is there any way I can highlight the range `A2:L2` and get Excel to automatically work out the amount that needs to be added for each cell (in this case it's `72`) and then fill in the blanks like so:

[image]

Currently I'm calculating the difference manually, putting `-199` into `B2` and then using the fill handle to complete the rest, but I suspect there is a quicker way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be a little faster if you select all cells from -271 to 521 inclusive and choose [**Home –> Editing –> Fill –> Series**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db). Excel will automatically select step 72, all you have to do is click OK